# ExpressJS - Send variable as response on POST request

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express

I am trying to retrieve insertId of the SQL and send it back to the front end. But when I do the res.send(result.insertId), I am getting a 500 Error. How can I deliver the insertId of the sql to the front end successfully?

```
router.post('/list', function(req, res, next) {
    var lastIncrement = 0;
    pool.getConnection(function (error, connection) {
        connection.query('INSERT INTO test_table SET Name = ?, Age = ?', [req.body.Name, req.body.Age], function (error, result) {
            if(error)
                console.error(error);
            lastIncrement = result.insertId;
            connection.release();
        });
    });
    res.send(lastIncrement);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one problem in your code for sure that you are returning before finishing the query. So you have to return from inside the callback function.

```
router.post('/list', function(req, res, next) {
var lastIncrement = 0;
pool.getConnection(function (error, connection) {
    connection.query('INSERT INTO test_table SET Name = ?, Age = ?', [req.body.Name, req.body.Age], function (error, result) {
        if(error)
            console.error(error);
        lastIncrement = result.insertId;
        connection.release();
        res.send(lastIncrement);
    });
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to asynchronous nature of nodejs your res.send is executing before the query returns the value. You can use a `.then` promise to ensure that the `res.send` happens after you get the value from query or have `res.send` after assigning the value.

You can try this:

```
pool.getConnection(function (error, connection) {
    connection.query('INSERT INTO test_table SET Name = ?, Age = ?', [req.body.Name, req.body.Age], function (error, result) {
        if(error)
            console.error(error);
        lastIncrement = result.insertId;
        connection.release();
    }).then(function(){
        res.send(lastIncrement);
    })
});
```